# Почему родительский объект не приводится к типу дочернего?

Tags: c++, функции, наследование

1) Пытаюсь запустить такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual void m() {
        std::cout << "A" ;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    void m() {
        std::cout << "B";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B *b;

    b = &(B)a;
    b->m();

    return 0;
}
```

Если в main прописать:

```
int main()
{
    A *a;
    B b;

    a = &b;
    a->m();

    return 0;
}
```

то все ожидаемо работает. Но вот вопрос, почему нельзя привести тип родителя к типу наследника, а наоборот можно? Как здесь работает механизм приведения типов? Или все же можно привести тип родителя к типу наследника?

1) Еще такой вопрос, если написать так:

```
struct A
{
     void m() {
        std::cout << "A" ;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    void m() {
        std::cout << "B";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *a;
    B b;

    a = &b;
    a->m();

    return 0;
}
```

то вызывается m() у обьекта A. Но объекта А как бы не существует. Мне не понятно, где же тогда вызывается эта m(), у какого объекта типа A если обьекта типа A не существует?

Comment: Объект А (последний код) какбэ существует. В объявляется как ссылка  на А

Comment: @DNS, неверно скопировал код. Поправил, сейчас объекта "а" не существует, а на выводе пишет "A"

Comment: Ух-ты... А если поменять `struct` на `class`? Вроде, так должна быть классика...

Comment: Какая разница, это не классика, это я просто так написал.

Comment: Проверил на ДЕВ-е. Таки да... Видимо работает приведение типов. А ссылается на "свою ф-цию". Но, в целом, я в невдомеке... Спасибо за сообщение..

Comment: с `class` то же самое... (только надо добавить `public`)

Comment: class и struct отличаются ничем. только спецификатором доступа, так что ожидаемо

Comment: Что за словесная каша в вопросе? В заголовке написано "Почему дочерний объект не приводится к типу родительского?". В коде же показано строго наоборот - что дочерний прекрасно приводится к типу родительского. И в тексте вопрос задан наоборот "почему нельзя привести тип родителя к типу наследника, а наоборот можно?". А ну-ка быстро доводить текст вопроса до вменяемого состояния! Пока что написана какая-то бессвязная самопротиворечивая белиберда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дочерний объект содержит в себе родительский объект, поэтому приведение дочернего объекта к родительскому объекту не вызывает проблем и может быть осуществлено неявно.

С другой стороны, родительский объект ничего не знает о том, какие и как могут быть определены дочерние от него объекты. Он такой информацией не обладает. А потому нет неявного преобразования из родительского объекта в какой-либо дочерний.

Когда нет виртуальных функций, то происходит статическое связывание вызываемых функций с типом объекта на этапе компиляции.

В этой программе

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
     void m() {
        std::cout << "A" ;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    void m() {
        std::cout << "B";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *a;
    B b;

    a = &b;
    a->m();

    return 0;
}
```

статическим типом указателя `a` является тип `struct A`, поэтому компилятор связывает функцию, объявленную в этом типе.

На самом деле то же самое происходит и для виртуальных функций, то есть компилятор осуществляет поиск имени функции в соответствии со статическим типом указателя или ссылки на объект. Другое дело, что вызов функции осуществляется с помощью механизма, использующего таблицу виртуальных функций. Адрес этой таблицы разрешается динамически на этапе выполнения программы, хотя в некоторых простых случаях, когда статический и динамический типы совпадают, то может это делать на этапе компиляции.

Answer (score 2):

привидение родителя к наследнику выполнять разрешается и это называется `downcast`,  которое можно делать, например, так

`b = static_cast<B*>(&a);`

А в вашем первом примере будет ошибка компиляции ввиду некорректного с точки зрения синтаксиса языка С++ кода `b = &(B)a;`

вероятно, вы хотели написать так

`b = (B*)&a;`

*edit*
ошибка компиляции будет, как отметил `Ant`, не с точки зрения синтаксиса а с точки зрения семантики языка С++

это каст в стиле С - которого лучше избегать, а в случае с `downcast` подавно - предпочтительнее применять специальные и более безопасные операторы явного приведения типов из С++ (как написано выше до этого)

А вобще, подобный `downcast` в некоторых случаях может приводить к неопределённому поведению

по поводу третьего вопроса - выводится `A` так как эта функция в родительском классе не виртуальна - в этом и основной смысл виртуальных функий - обеспечение вызова переопределённого в наследнике родительского метода через указатель на базовый класс (родительский класс), соответственно если в базовом классе функция не виртуальна то он и вызовется

Comment: В выражении `b = &(B)a` нет ничего "некорректного с точки зрения синтаксиса". С *синтаксисом* тут как раз таки все в полном порядке: значение `a` приводится к типу `B`, к результату приведения применяется оператор `&` и его результат записывается в `b`. *Семантика* всего этого в контексте данного примера, однако, ошибочна.

Comment: @AnT этот выражение не скомпилируется на компиляторе от `g++` следовательно он некорректен

Comment: Во-первых, в языке С++ нет понятия "скомпилируется/не скомпилируется". Во-вторых, компилируемость кода в *конкретном* компиляторе не значит вообще ничего. Во-третьих, еще раз повторю суть: ничего синтаксически некорректного в этом выражении нет. Какие-либо проблемы в этом выражении *синтаксическими* не являются. С синтаксисом тут все в полном и идеальном порядке.

Comment: @AnT ну этот код на большинстве компиляторов не будет компилироваться... да и не ясно почему тогда ошибка выдаётся во время компиляции - тоесть я так понимаю семантические ошибки также входят в группу ошибок `at compile time` получается ?

Comment: Разумеется входят. Не составить труда придумать такие определения переменных `a`, `b` и типа `B`, при которых это выражение будет корректным. Что означает, что с синтаксисом у него проблем нет.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, **ampawd**!

Я прозрел! Код ниже выводит ВВ, как и *типа* ожидалось

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{public:
     virtual void m() {
        std::cout << "A" ;
    }
};

class B : public A
{public:
    void m() {
        std::cout << "B";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *a;
    B b;

    a = &b;
    a->m();
    b.m();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста (ещё 5 символов нужно)

Comment: @ampawd, а без крипты? )))